# Why this getOrDefault(key, value) method is not working in this code?

Tags: java, string, dictionary, compiler-errors, default

In this code, i am trying to map each character to a counter that represents its occurrence. However, in line 7 (int count = map.getOrDefault(chars[i], 0);), there is an compile error that says:

Solution.java:7: error: cannot find symbol
Integer count = map.getOrDefault(chars[i], 0);
^
symbol:   method getOrDefault(char,int)
location: variable map of type HashMap<Character,Integer>
1 error
Why is that?

```
static String isValid(String s) {
        HashMap<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
        char[] chars = s.toCharArray();
        int N = chars.length;
        boolean chance = true;
        for(int i = 0 ; i < N ; i++){
            int count = map.getOrDefault(chars[i], 0);
            if(count >= 1){
                if(chance)
                    chance = false;
                else
                    return "NO";
            }
            map.put(chars[i], count + 1);
        }
        return "YES"; 
    }
```

Comment: Probably need to cast explicitly. `Character` is not `char` and `Integer` is not `int`

Comment: The code works for me. What Java version do you use?

Comment: In addition to what Simon said, are you sure to have imported `java.util.Map` and not some other type?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to check your imports. Maybe the Map import is a wrong one, be sure to use
`import java.util.*;`. The * will import everything of the `java.util` package, just to safe ;).

I hope I could help you, keep up your work!

Answer (score 0):

I believe `getOrDefault` is available only from Java 8. Make sure you are running on Java 8 or higher.